# How do i exclude most of my html from the jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, menu

I'm working on a website for a project, where I need my menu bar to be fixed on top even when the user scrolls down.It's an one-page website. I can't seem to make that happen. Also, I have a problem with my navigation. I have the following jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
```

I had some elements in my site where you click on a image/button a new div slides out underneath it. But since i put the jquery (here above) in, every time I click on a button or image the jquery throws me to the object instead of just sliding it out like it used to. Here the code i had to make it slide:

```
$(function () {
    $('.showSingle').click(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(href)
        var div = $(href).slideToggle('slow');
        $(".targetDiv").not(div).slideUp('slow')
        return false
    })
});
```

So, my questions are: How do I write the code for the menu in a way that it doesn't affect the rest of my code? I'd like to exclude some parts of my html in jquery.

And if it's possible, I'd like to figure out how to stick my menu to the top of my page, and my header image to start directly underneath it, but the menu should scroll with the user.

Comment: place the parent of the element in `$('a[href^="#"]')` like `$('li a[href^="#"]')` so the clicks don't have conflicts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place the parent of the element in `$('a[href^="#"]')` like `$('li a[href^="#"]')` so the clicks don't have conflicts

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class on the buttons you want to target. Like `<button class="dropdown">` on dropdown buttons, and `<button class="scroller">` on sroller buttons (or links or whatever).

Then, using jQuery, target only the dropdowns or scrolling buttons by using

```
$("button.dropdown").click(function(){
    // do something
})
```

or

```
$("button.scroller").click(function(){
    // do something else
})
```

So the solution is not to target *everything except* certain elements; it's to target only the elements you want to act on.

For a sticky header, just use `header{ position:fixed }` in CSS. There are loads of tutorials about it around, like [this one](http://cssreset.com/creating-fixed-headers-with-css/).